# How to get ObjectId correctly in CoreData IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios7, nsmanagedobjectid

I am trying to store my unique records using CoreData ObjectId.Sometimes i am succeded to get ObjectID in this format

```
<x-coredata://FC004E6F-F3D6-420E-871E-3E281571FB8B/Register/p4>
```

through which i am able to retreive the id i.e 4.But sometimes it return in this format of ObjectId

```
<x-coredata:///Playlist/tC481615F-4ABA-4CDA-B703-D1E6303B455D3>
```

i.e NSTemporaryObjectID_Default which is so irritating.I clean my project from my IOS Simulator,Clean Xcode but it is not working perfectly.

**This is my code to get object ID:**

```
-(IBAction)TestButton:(id)sender
{
    appObject=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context =[appObject managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *playlistContact;
    NSManagedObjectID *moID = [playlistContact objectID];
    NSString *aString = [[moID URIRepresentation] absoluteString];
    NSArray *theComponents = [aString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/p"];
    NSInteger theZpk = [[theComponents lastObject] intValue];
    playlistId=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)theZpk];
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using `ObjectID` for that.  If you are looking to use a primary key you really should be creating your own primary key and fetching off of that instead.

The `ObjectID` can and will change on you in several different situations causing numerous problems.  It is intended to be used within the application during one life-cycle of the app.  Using it across life cycles is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

To get `objectID` use:

```
-(NSManagedObject *)existingObjectWithID:(NSManagedObjectID *)objectID
                               error:(NSError **)error
```

To get permanent `objectID` use `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects`, for example:

```
NSManagedObject *contact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:self.entityName inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSError *error = nil;
if (![context obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:
      @[contact] error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Couldn't obtain a permanent ID for object %@",
          error);
}
```